# Parse error in template argument list, expected identifier

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++14, mingw

I'm trying to compile the [EnTT library](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/releases) (version 2.7.3 for cpp14) using MinGW GCC-6.3.0 in Eclipse Oxygen. When compiling, I get these errors:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++1y -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++14 -o "source\\main.o" "..\\source\\main.cpp" 
In file included from c:\mingw\include\entt\entt.hpp:10:0,
                 from ..\source\includes.hpp:23,
                 from ..\source\main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp: In function 'void entt::connect(entt::Sink<void(entt::Registry<Entity>&, Entity)>)':
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp:56:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     sink.template connect<dependency<Entity, Dependency...>>();
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp:56:19: error: expected identifier
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp: In function 'void entt::disconnect(entt::Sink<void(entt::Registry<Entity>&, Entity)>)':
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp:79:19: error: parse error in template argument list
     sink.template disconnect<dependency<Entity, Dependency...>>();
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\entt\entity/helper.hpp:79:19: error: expected identifier
```

Here are the truculent functions in question:

```
template<typename Entity, typename... Component>
void dependency(Registry<Entity> &registry, const Entity entity) {
    using accumulator_type = int[];
    accumulator_type accumulator = { ((registry.template has<Component>(entity) ? void() : (registry.template assign<Component>(entity), void())), 0)... };
    (void)accumulator;
}

template<typename... Dependency, typename Entity>
inline void connect(Sink<void(Registry<Entity> &, const Entity)> sink) {
    sink.template connect<dependency<Entity, Dependency...>>();
}

template<typename... Dependency, typename Entity>
inline void disconnect(Sink<void(Registry<Entity> &, const Entity)> sink) {
    sink.template disconnect<dependency<Entity, Dependency...>>();
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have just hit the exact same issue with the same library. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @drglove I didn't find a solution, I ended up using [this ECS library](https://github.com/redxdev/ECS) instead.